# How to configure secure_headers to use external cookies?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, cookies, header, http-headers

## Problem

`SameSite: none` seem to not work for me.  `samesite` `lax` works with a cookie from my application, but I can't find configuration that supports external cookies, from google analytics etc.

#### Expected outcome

There are no warnings in Firefox about `SameSite` for external cookies.

#### Config

```
  config.hsts = "max-age=#{2.years.to_i}"
  config.x_content_type_options = "nosniff"
  config.referrer_policy = "origin-when-cross-origin"
  config.csp = {
    default_src: %w('self'),
    font_src: %w('self' data:),
    img_src: %w('self' data: https://myapp.mydomain.com),
    object_src: %w('none'),
    script_src: %w('self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *.nr-data.net *.google-analytics.com *.googletagmanager.com *.newrelic.com blob:),
    style_src: %w('self' 'unsafe-inline'),
    worker_src: %w('self' 'unsafe-inline' blob:),
    connect_src: %w('self' *.nr-data.net *.google-analytics.com *.googletagmanager.com *.newrelic.com)
  }
  config.cookies = {
    secure: true,
    httponly: true,
    samesite: {
      lax: { only: ['_myapp_session'] },
      none: { only: ['_ga', '_gid', '_gat', '_ga_XXXXXXXXX'] }
    }
  }
end
```

#### Errors

In Firefox console:

```
Cookie “_ga” does not have a proper “SameSite” attribute value. Soon, cookies without the “SameSite” attribute or with an invalid value will be treated as “Lax”. This means that the cookie will no longer be sent in third-party contexts. If your application depends on this cookie being available in such contexts, please add the “SameSite=None“ attribute to it. To know more about the “SameSite“ attribute, read https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite [analytics.js:27:576](https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js)
Cookie “_gid” does not have a proper “SameSite” attribute value. Soon, cookies without the “SameSite” attribute or with an invalid value will be treated as “Lax”. This means that the cookie will no longer be sent in third-party contexts. If your application depends on this cookie being available in such contexts, please add the “SameSite=None“ attribute to it. To know more about the “SameSite“ attribute, read https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite [analytics.js:27:576](https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js)
Cookie “_gat” does not have a proper “SameSite” attribute value. Soon, cookies without the “SameSite” attribute or with an invalid value will be treated as “Lax”. This means that the cookie will no longer be sent in third-party contexts. If your application depends on this cookie being available in such contexts, please add the “SameSite=None“ attribute to it. To know more about the “SameSite“ attribute, read https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite [analytics.js:27:576](https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js)
Cookie “_ga_VKH9NH625Z” does not have a proper “SameSite” attribute value. Soon, cookies without the “SameSite” attribute or with an invalid value will be treated as “Lax”. This means that the cookie will no longer be sent in third-party contexts. If your application depends on this cookie being available in such contexts, please add the “SameSite=None“ attribute to it. To know more about the “SameSite“ attribute, read https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite
```

And

```
Request to access cookie or storage on “<URL>” was blocked because it came from a tracker and content blocking is enabled. 8
Request to access cookie or storage on “https://js-agent.newrelic.com/async-api.30bd804e-1.236.0.min.js” was blocked because it came from a tracker and content blocking is enabled.

Request to access cookie or storage on “https://js-agent.newrelic.com/860.03a8b7a5-1.236.0.min.js” was blocked because it came from a tracker and content blocking is enabled.

Request to access cookie or storage on “https://js-agent.newrelic.com/session-manager.2a64278a-1.236.0.min.js” was blocked because it came from a tracker and content blocking is enabled.

Request to access cookie or storage on “https://js-agent.newrelic.com/lazy-feature-loader.2f55ce66-1.236.0.min.js” was blocked because it came from a tracker and content blocking is enabled.

Request to access cookie or storage on “https://js-agent.newrelic.com/148.1a20d5fe-1.236.0.min.js” was blocked because it came from a tracker and content blocking is enabled.

Request to access cookie or storage on “https://js-agent.newrelic.com/page_view_event-aggregate.06482edd-1.236.0.min.js” was blocked because it came from a tracker and content blocking is enabled.

Request to access cookie or storage on “https://js-agent.newrelic.com/page_view_timing-aggregate.bd6de33a-1.236.0.min.js” was blocked because it came from a tracker and content blocking is enabled.

Request to access cookie or storage on “https://js-agent.newrelic.com/metrics-aggregate.3dc53903-1.236.0.min.js” was blocked because it came from a tracker and content blocking is enabled.
```

#### Generated headers

Set-Cookie:
`_myapp_session=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%3D--b34405b4ed7a5af671742c0c895bb91f9bc03f29;  path=/; expires=Fri, 28-Jul-2023 21:15:13 GMT; secure; HttpOnly;  SameSite=Lax`

Cookie:

`_ga=GA1.2.173371247.1691232864;  _gid=GA1.2.1916219553.1612332864;  _myapp_session=BAh7CkkiD3Nlc3Npb25aaZQGOgZFVEkiJTMxYzY3ODY3ODlmZjI1MTE5YzJjYTBjMTk4NWE5MDZhBjsAVEkiC2xvY2FsZQY7AEY6B3BsSSIZd2FyZGVuLnVzZXIudXNlci5rZXkGOwBIWwdbBmkCgQVJIiIkMmEkMTAkZFRqWHZVRGYwYS9GSVgyUUhveERKTwY7AFRJIhRzaG93X25ld3NfbW9kYWwGOwBGRkkiEF9jc3JmX3Rva2VuBjsARkkiMWIxOHdvUHJmQ0ljVkV1RmpXVXlscm0waTc4MXo0U2GaMDlqV045RHArdXM9BjsARg%3D%3D--61e9e2278d76f644442df9174a27f8667ccf016e;  _ga_VKH9NH625Z=GS1.2.1663769319.2.1.1697520980.0.0.0`